# mysql ETIMEDOUT when connect from Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The following code is to issue mysql query with Firebase Cloud Functions.

The code works when running on the local machine. ( `$ firebase serve` )
But when running on the Google Cloud Platform, the error `ETIMEDOUT` occur. ( `$ firebase deploy` )

I want you to tell me the possible causes.

NOTE
- Cloud Functions runtime config is `Node.js 8` and my local env is also Node.js 8.0.0

Code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '10.20.30.40',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db',
  connectTimeout : 10000
})

pool.query('SELECT * FROM table', (error, rows, fields) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
    throw error
  }

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows)

  pool.end()
})
```

Error:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:411:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (/srv/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
    at Promise (/srv/lib/modules/myCellar.js:32:14)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.get.uid [as get] (/srv/lib/modules/myCellar.js:31:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/index.js:14:36)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

Comment: Check if the port is allowed to connect.

Comment: I found the following error message that may be the cause.  
    "Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions"